# Google Charts Show Empty Items in Legend

Tags: google-visualization

When working with the pie chart in Google Charts it seems to ignore items with a value of zero.  I would really like to get these items to show up in the legend even though their value is zero so that the users knows that it was a possible answer to the question. Is there a way to have a zero value item still show up in the legend?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting the slice visibility threshold to 0 solved it for me. Notice the last option `sliceVisibilityThreshold`.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {
    title:'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
    width:400,
    height:300,
    sliceVisibilityThreshold:0
});
```

(taken from the sample pie chart).

By default, the threshold is set to 1/720, which means (from the docs):

> The slice relative part, below which a slice will not show individually. All slices that
>   have not passed this threshold will be combined to a single slice, whose size is the sum 
>   of all their sizes. Default is not to show individually any slice which is smaller than 
>   half a degree.