# I need to display quantitative values in a Google Charts legend, but traditional solutions aren't working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to make some pie charts for a website. I need the chart to display the values of all data in the legend, even if their value = 0, or is very small compared to the other data. I've tried the solution proposed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422141/display-item-in-legend-even-if-value-0-with-google-charts-tools-pie-chart) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752518/google-charts-show-empty-items-in-legend), but setting "sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0" does not make the legend display all values in the legend. Anyone know how to do this?

Here's what the chart looks like, as well as the data: 
[Google Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6maY.png). (I'm apparently not allowed to embed images).

This is what I tried:

```
var options = {
              title: 'Dummy Title', 
              pieSliceText: 'value', 
              pieSliceTextStyle: {color: 'white', fontName: 'Arial Black', fontSize: 15},
              sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
              legend: {position: 'labeled', labeledValueText: 'value'}
            };
```

Comment: need to see why `sliceVisibilityThreshold` doesn't work for you, is there enough room on the chart? if you could share a working example, image of the chart, or a sample of the data, it would be easier to investigate...

Comment: Added an image of the chart and a console showing my data. I can post my full code as well, if needed.

Comment: looks like you need to increase the `height` and `width`